# Application spyder launch may have produced errors windows

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

In my windows 10 , when I am attempting to open spyder by anaconda navigator , this happens :
`Application spyder launch may have produced errors Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in  sys.exit(main()) File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 190, in main from spyder.app import mainwindow File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 51, in  requirements.check_spyder_kernels() File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\requirements.py", line 66, in check_spyder_kernels % actual_ver) File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\requirements.py", line 24, in show_warning raise RuntimeError(message) RuntimeError: Please check Spyder installation requirements: spyder-kernels`

I have tried installing pyqt and did conda update --all .But nothing works ...
Please help .Thanks in advance.
versions : spyder - 3.3.1 python - 3.6.6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This problem is caused by running `conda update --all`, which (in my opinion) is a bad strategy because it tries to install all packages without respecting the restrictions imposed by some packages on others.

In this case, Spyder **3.3+** demands `spyder-kernels` **<1.0**, but `conda update --all` installs `spyder-kernels` **1.0.1** and that breaks Spyder with the error above.

So the solution to this problem is the following:

1. Open an Anaconda Prompt
2. Run there the following commands

   ```
   conda remove spyder-kernels
   conda install spyder-kernels=0.*
   ```
3. Stop using `conda update --all`, or you'll get the same problem again.