# Anaconda Navigator (Jupyter Notebook error)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to launch jupyter and spyder from Anaconda Navigator but am not able to do so. It continuously throws errors.

Error:  Application notebook launch may have produced errors. Exit code: 3221225614

Things I have done:   Installing and Uninstalling twice today but no result.

If I install Spyder from outside i.e. without Anaconda it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I have two guesses on this problem, maybe you can try these. I'll just shoot my ideas to help :)

Firstly, the problem might be about kernels and you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52694811/10926848) solution. Moreover, if this works for Spyder, you can try a similar approach for Jupyter Notebook too.

Secondly, it might be a problem with your Python installation, I might recommend reinstalling or upgrading either Python or Anaconda (since you tried reinstalling Anaconda, you can pass that step).

Comment: Thanks brother but it didn't came handy.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue with jupyter notebook. i removed anaconda and reinstalled it and updated it but didn't work.
Open an Anaconda Prompt
Run there the following command

conda update --all

the problem is solved.